# Corebluetooth: How to force iPhone to pair to unpaired peripheral

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

How to force iPhone to pair to unpaired peripheral when peripheral has the pairing information.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API for responding to the bonding process in Core Bluetooth.

If the peripheral doesn't require encryption then pairing will happen automatically when the iOS device connects to the peripheral.

If an attribute requires encryption then a pairing (actually bonding) dialog will be shown to the user by iOS when your app attempts to read/write the encrypted data. At this point the user will need to enter the PIN. There is no API that allows your app to complete the bonding without user intervention.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am doubtful about the recovery when central or peripheral deletes pairing data.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  If bonding has occurred (the user entered a PIN via the dialog) then that data can only be removed by the user selecting "forget this device" in settings, in which case bonding will occur again (with another prompt) when the device is reconnected as long as the peripheral detects that the bonding has been lost.  If there is no bonding then the connection will just happen.

Comment: What will be the case when user deletes pairing from from peripheral without deleting from central?

Comment: iOS should detect the invalid bonding information and re-initiate the bonding process

Comment: What will be the case when user deletes pairing from from peripheral without deleting from central? For example, i have tried with one iphone as peripheral and other as central. While connecting iOS displays passcode entry popup when tries to subscribe "CBCharacteristicPropertyNotifyEncryptionRequired" characteristics. During next try i have deleted pairing data from one of the device and iphone did not show passcode entry popup and "didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic" not called.

Comment: Then you will probably need to "forget this device" on both devices to ensure that all keys have been erased

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92213/discussion-between-sps-and-paulw11).